# WPF Window inside WinForm let application hang

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

When I open a WPF window inside my WinForms-Application, the whole Application hangs after MainForm has closed and Main-Method has left. Only a Environment.Exit(0) helps. But this is a hack-solution. Is there another trick I missed?

Starting MainForm in Application.Run-Loop

```cs
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
        // Environment.Exit(0); -> only this helps.
    }
```

MainForm Button1: Showing HostedWpfForm and pure WpfWindow

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this hosted wpf control inside winform window causes no problems
        // new HostedWpfForm(new WpfUserControl()).Show();

        // this pure wpf window hangs after closing MainForm and exit Main
        // only Environment.Exit(0) at the end of Program.Main helps to close!
        WpfWindow wpfwnd = new WpfWindow();
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwnd);
        wpfwnd.Show();
    }
}
```

HostedWpfForm looks like this and causes no problems

```cs
public partial class HostedWpfForm : Form
{
    public HostedWpfForm(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
        host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        host.Child = uiElement;
        Controls.Add(host);
    }
}
```

WpfUserControl

```cs
public partial class WpfUserControl : UserControl
{
    public WpfUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

WpfWindow which causes problems

```cs
public partial class WpfWindow : Window
{
    public WpfWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

By the way: I added these ProjectTypeGuids to be able to add Wpf-Window in project.

```xml
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Does anybody know, why a pure wpf window causes these hanging problems?

Comment: It will hang when there's another thread around, use Debug > Windows > Threads to find out what it is doing.  Watch out for a DoEvents hack.  The Visual Studio Hosting process can act up in this scenario.  Use Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the code above the problem can be reproduced. As you can see there is no DoEvents in it. Also the Threads Window shows only unmanaged framework threads. Switching off the vs hosting process give several other disadvantages.